# jupyter notebook: Couldn't authenticate WebSocket connection

Tags: nginx, websocket, jupyter

I have a docker for jupyter and nginx.

My nginx config file is

```
upstream jupyter {
    server jupyter:8888;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://jupyter;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }


    location ~* /(api/kernels/[^/]+/(channels|iopub|shell|stdin)|terminals/websocket)/? {
        proxy_pass            http://jupyter;
        proxy_set_header      Host $host;
        # websocket support
        proxy_http_version    1.1;
        proxy_set_header      Upgrade "websocket";
        proxy_set_header      Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout    86400;
    }
}
```

When i try to connect to jupyter, i get the following error

```
jupyter_1     | [W 05:28:50.820 NotebookApp] Couldn't authenticate WebSocket connection
jupyter_1     | [W 05:28:50.822 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/kernels/e4880672-4886-4f2a-8d59-29aa52c6a678/channels?session_id=572adeaf20c84488886ba93b304f51af (172.19.0.4) 5.660000ms referer=None
nginx_1       | 172.19.0.1 - - [09/May/2021:05:28:50 +0000] "GET /api/kernels/e4880672-4886-4f2a-8d59-29aa52c6a678/channels?session_id=572adeaf20c84488886ba93b304f51af HTTP/1.1" 403 7052 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

If i dont use nginx, everything works fine, i.e only the jupyter docker

Any idea whats causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

I changed the nginx configuration and it worked

```
upstream jupyter {
    server jupyter:8888;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name jyp.*;

    location / {
        # or whichever port you've set for your Jupyter
        proxy_pass http://jupyter;
        # $http_host is important for accessing Jupyter locally
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        # http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I got this from https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2020/05/27/jupyter-notebook-nginx/

I cant understand how this configuration is working and previous one not working.

Also at github i found this. https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/625#issuecomment-362985148

[image]

If any one can explain what this does, it will be helpul